# How to change the location of configuration files for Zoom?

Tags: zoom-sdk

My computer admin has made a frustrating change recently that's broken a lot of things on my work PC that I'm just trying to progressively fix. They have changed the name of a directory so where previously the configuration file for Zoom used to be saved in H:/AppData, it's now saved in OneDrive:/USER/AppData. Predictably, this means I can't open Zoom because it can't find the AppData. Is there a way to change where Zoom is looking for the configuration file (and AppData) without having to uninstall and reinstall?